# "Golang is more productive because any type can be given methods". How does that increase productivity?

Tags: go

I was watching [Google IO 2010 - GO Programming video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgVhBThJdXc) where they claim (see 32:38)

"GO can make programming very productive because 
 - any type can be given methods, which opens up interesting design possibilities"

Can somebody please explain how can this feature increase productivity? Is this feature not present in other languages?

Comment: Function types can have methods in Go. Take a look at http.handlerFunc (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) which is a function type and implements a methods. Java does not have this feature. Regarding "productivity": This might be controversial. It definitively allows to write more types of code and allows interesting designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, that means you can add methods to predefined types (well, not really them, but types derived from them).

For instance, if you have a list of `Foo` (where `Foo` is a type you or another package defined) and want to make that list sortable, you just have to make the list implement `sort.Interface`. To do so, you just define a new type

```
type fooSlice []Foo
```

and define methods on it to implement the interface :

```
func (fs fooSlice) Len() int { return len(fs) }
func (fs fooSlice) Swap(a, b int) { fs[a], fs[b] = fs[b], fs[a] }
func (fs fooSlice) Less(a, b int) bool { return fs[a].Ord() < fs[b].Ord() }
```

Then, everywhere you have a slice of `Foo`, you can cast it as a `fooSlice` and use it with `sort.Sort` :

```
func sortAndDoStuff(foos []Foo) {
    sort.Sort(fooSlice(foos))
    doStuff(foos)
}
```

Doing that with, say, Java, would require a lot more plumbing, because you would need a new class, make it have one field (the `[]Foo`), say it implements an interface, implement said methods (as with go) and make methods that goes back and forth between `[]Foo` and `fooSlice` classes.

Answer (score 4):

in java or c#, you need declare a class to inherit/implement from some interface. but in golang, the declaration is not required, just write the methods for the interfaces you want to implement.

it is more flexible, so it increases productivity in some way, I suppose.

Comment: I think your answer is describing the 'implicit type hierarchy' in Go. This is obviously a good feature and explained in the video. See slide at 32:38 in the video. This is mentioned as the second point. My question is about the first point.